# HTML: how to make 2 tables with different CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to put two tables (on the same page) which should render differently (i.e. use different CSS for each table). Is it possible?

Comment: Assign different CSS classes to each?

Comment: This is a very good question. Why is it labelled off-topic??? According to the tags, it is very on-topic!  I think that this "banning" does not meet Stack Overflow guidelines and that such bannings  must be banned! :)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

In your html

```
<table class="table1">
<tr>
<td>
...
</table>

<table class="table2">

<tr>
<td>
...
</table>
```

In your css:

```
table.table1 {...}
table.table1 tr {...}
table.table1 td {...}

table.table2 {...}
table.table2 tr {...}
table.table2 td {...}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to assign different classes to each table.

Create a class in CSS with the dot '.' operator and write your properties inside each class. For example,

```
.table1 {
//some properties
}

.table2 {
//Some other properties
}
```

and use them in your html code.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, just assign seperate css classes to both tables.

```
<table class="style1"></table>
<table class="style2"></table>
```

.css

```
table.style1 { //your css here}
table.style2 { //your css here}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<table id="table1"></table>
<table id="table2"></table>
```

or

```
<table class="table1"></table>
<table class="table2"></table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course it is!

Give them both an `id` and set up the CSS accordingly:

```
#table1
{
    CSS for table1
}


#table2
{
    CSS for table2
}
```