# kml file properties overriden by CSS in webpage

Tags: html, kml, css-tables

I have a map which loads a kml file at some point.
The kml contains trails with infowindows created in Google Earth using html.
the problem is that when I load it on the website, its properties are overridden by the rest of the code for attributes like: background color, table sizes, borders etc.

1. For example: I use a table to put map & legends together, but these
   table properties are inherited by the kml file, and the infowindows are formatted the
   way the rest of the page does..

What could I do to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the infowindow proprerties table, td, etc inheritted the css in my main page. This happenned because I used  inside the kml infowindows and for web page styling. The solution was very simple as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992198/html-how-to-make-2-tables-with-different-css) as well.
I used different table classes and that solved the problem :D

Answer (score 0):

better try using iframe like this 
`<body>
        <iframe width="700" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=https:%2F%2Fraw.github.com%2Fthroughnothing%2Fgpx%2Fmaster%2F2012%2F20120629.kml&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;output=embed">
</iframe><br />
 </body>`

refer this link https://gist.github.com/throughnothing/3074654